# merge replication processing order of UPDATEs, INSERTs and DELETEs

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I can set the order of Merge Replication? I've read that the order is Delete -> Update -> Delete. I can change it? If so, how can it impact in my replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot change the order in which changes are applied.  You can however change the order of articles being processed - see sp_addmergearticle and parameter @processing_order.